# How to make a Kindle file from LaTeX

Tags: ebook, kindle

I've looked around on this site and did some Google searches, but I haven't found an answer. I want to take my TeX document and convert it to a Kindle format that can uploaded to the Kindle Digital Platform. I already have the code written, which is suited for producing a PDF.

Comment: I want to make a Kindle e-book from my existing code.

Comment: The PDF finally converted to Kindle on the site.

Comment: And what Kindle you have? I have no problems sending PDF's to `*@kindle.com` email...

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem very well. I'm not trying to upload a PDF to a Kindle reading device. In fact, I don't even have one. I'm a publisher who uses LaTeX to format books. I used to use MS Word for formatting print books and Kindle e-books, but since I no longer use Word, I wanted to used LaTeX. I thought there might be a way to convert the LaTeX code to a Kindle format.

Comment: If you don't want to use a PDF you can use Calibre to convert it into a .mobi file which can natively used on Kindles.

Comment: See the Kindle book/guide on this by Graham Bevan: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147360/how-to-make-a-kindle-file-from-latex

Answer (score 21):

You can try [tex4ebook](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook). It can output epub, epub3 and mobi formats. It is based on `tex4ht` and you must have `kindlegen` app installed in order to generate `mobi` format for kindle.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon provides a **guide**:

https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A37Z49E2DDQPP3&

and

https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A17W8UM0MMSQX6

The **supported formats** for example can be found here:

https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A2GF0UFHIYG9VQ